# Null values when linking to blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working with a workbook where it is having to link to multiple sheets. The problem I'm running into is that when I link to a blank cell, it will display a 0 on my master sheet. This runs into a problem since we have conditional formatting and because some of the cells can be a 0. Is there a way to have Excel just display a blank value when the other field is blank. This is the formula I am using to link the sheets.

=[56.9_PS_Spar_Cap_Thickness.xlsx]Sheet1!D89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF([56.9_PS_Spar_Cap_Thickness.xlsx]Sheet1!D89="","",[56.9_PS_Spar_Cap_Thickness.xlsx]Sheet1!D89)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great and did everything I needed.

Comment: @vxd128 Thanks for the feedback.